# Created By name and alias is not available in field set for contact

Tags: apex, salesforce-classic, fieldsets

In my org, there is a custom object named `Customer` which has a lookup to `Contact`. I am creating a fieldset for the object. In the fieldset, I wish to add the name or alias of the person who created the contact. If I add `Created By`, it comes as `Contact_ID__r.CreatedById` in apex. I want the name or alias and not the ID.

I referred to the [salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_field_sets.htm&type=5). I found the following sentence:

> NOTE Only fields available in the API can be added to field sets.

Is it the case that Created By name or alias is not available in the API? Is there a way I can add it to the fieldset?

**Please see the screenshots:**

[image: sc1]

[image: sc2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact `Created By` is a lookup to User object and hence, (*field api name: CreatedById*) displays the referenced record ID. This is the default behavior of audit fields like CreatedById & LastModifiedById in Salesforce.

You need to create a formula field in Contact object with return type as `text` and value as `CreatedBy.Alias`. You can then use this formula field in the field set of custom object.